# Number of three-tuples such that $c_1a_1 + c_2a_2 + c_3a_3 = n$ and $c_1 \ge c_2 \ge c_3$

Tags: combinatorics, logic, algorithms, generating-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to find the number of three tuples that sum up to $n$ when each element has a weight of $c_i$. In other words, how many combinations are there of $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ such that $c_1a_1 + c_2a_2 + c_3a_3 = n$ with the restriction that $c_1 \ge c_2 \ge c_3$. I tried to do this with a generating series, but it led nowhere unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Just to make things more clearer, $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ and $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$.

Second Edit: Thanks to @Blitzer. I realized afterward that $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3$ is indeed something I forgot to add.

Comment: Do you mean $a_1>=a_2>=a_3$?

Comment: How about a simple brute force approach? Loop through the possible values of$a_1$. Then for $a_2$. Then see if $a_3$ is an integer.

Comment: I'm more inclined to see the mathematical approach. And no, I mean $c_1 \ge c_2 \ge c_3$. The $c_i$'s are more of a weight assigned to each of $a_i$'s if that makes sense.

Comment: All numbers are integers?

Comment: All numbers are non-negative integers. Yes

Comment: I would suggest computing some special cases and then search the OEIS to start. I doubt that there will be a general closed-form, however you could try to guess one starting from the special cases found on OEIS. For example, for $c_1=1, c_2=2, c_3=3$ you get [A000601](https://oeis.org/A000601), for $c_1=1, c_2=2, c_3=4$ you get [A008804](https://oeis.org/A008804), $c_1=2, c_2=3, c_3=5$ you get [A008669](https://oeis.org/A008669).

Comment: Another idea is to try to start with two terms only.

Comment: Interesting. So right now, I basically have a triple nested summation for the generating series of all integers $n$. Something like $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{i}\sum_{k = 0}^{j} x^{c_1i + c_2j + c_3 k}$ which enforces the restrictions, but trying to reduce it down to a nice formula leaves me with something ugly. What are your thoughts on this approach?

Comment: Well, my first hint was without the restriction $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3$. $c_1 \ge c_2 \ge c_3$ alone wasn't an actual restriction.

Comment: Yeah I realized that afterwards, cuz the ordering of the elements are arbitrary. Sorry about that!

Comment: From numerical evidence the generating function should be $\frac{1}{(1-x^c_1)(1-x^{c_1+c_2})(1-x^{c_1+c_2+c_3})}$. I think it should not be too difficult to see why. After this you can get a linear recurrence and compute the desired number $f(n)$ for $n \ge 3c_1+2c_2+c_3$ as a linear combination of $7$ preceding terms.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense, thank you so much! I think the sum of sum of sums series i listed there might work out to something similar to this but this is definitely a lot cleaner!